# How to find the most appearances of a value having count > 7

Tags: mysql, sql

table name: d_risposte
id: index, unique not relevant
reply: from 1 to 4

```
id | reply | user
-----------------
  |   1   |  a34
  |   2   |  a34
  |   1   |  a34
  |   3   |  a34
  |   2   |  a34
  |   4   |  a34
  |   1   |  a34
  |   1   |  a34
  |   4   |  a55
  |   2   |  a55
  |   2   |  a55
  |   4   |  a71
  |   4   |  a71
  |   1   |  a71
  |   3   |  a71
  |   4   |  a71
  |   2   |  a71
  |   4   |  a71 
  |   4   |  a71 
  |   2   |  b22
  |   4   |  b22
  |   2   |  b22
```

i want keep only users with begin with "a" and has at least 7 reply,
then
i want count the majority of kind of replay 1..4 in this case the result should be:

```
   user | top_reply
   ----------------
   a34  |  1         (becouse the 1 reply appears 4 times)
   a71  |  4         (becouse the 4 reply appears 5 times)
```

(if it's tie, doent matters)

so my query is:

```
SELECT user FROM `d_risposte` WHERE user LIKE 'a%' group by user having count(*) > 7
```

the table result should be:

```
user
----
a34
a71
```

then i should count the majority of reply:
but i dont know how to do in just one query,
i try something like that...

```
SELECT reply, COUNT(reply) AS fooCount FROM d_risposte WHERE user ????????? GROUP BY reply ORDER BY COUNT(reply) DESC LIMIT 1
```

i cant figure it out :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an interesting question, try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.user,
       (SELECT s.reply FROM d_risposte s
        WHERE s.user = t.user
        GROUP BY s.reply
        ORDER BY count(*) DESC limit 1) as top_reply
FROM d_risposte t
INNER JOIN(SELECT d.user FROM d_risposte d
           WHERE d.user like 'a%'
           GROUP BY d.user
           HAVING count(*) > 6) t2
 ON(t2.user = t.user)
```

This will basically select for each user the `top_reply` , and then join to a table to filter those who have less then 7 records and doesn't start with `a`

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 't1.user' in 'on clause'

Comment: now works, but the results is:
a34   1
a34   1
a34   1 (many times) then
a71   4 (reapeaterd too)

Comment: i try to add DISTINCT @sagi

Comment: Yea do that, either distinct or group by should work it out. @Jotaro

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with two aggregations:

```
Select user,
      Substring_index(group_concat(reply order by cnt desc), ',', 1) as reply
From (select user, reply, count(*) as can't
      From d_riposte
      Group by user, reply) ur
Group by user
Having sum(cnt) >= 7
```